:h for C-h in Evil Mode
I use Evil Mode in Emacs and in Vim, you can write :h to bring up help. In Evil Mode, this works with :help but not with :h. Is this expected behaviour for the mode? If so, how can I make :h do the same thing that :help does?

As you observed, in evil mode the command :h is incomplete. Try the following:

Enable the menu mode, it has a special menu item Help, which shows many possible subjects.
Install the package which-key, and when typing C-h (the help system in Emacs) will show you all key to press further to access the subject of interest for you.

